# Why was the Burj Khalifa lit up in the colors of the Indian Flag on India Republic Day

Tags: india, foreign-policy, political-leaders, united-arab-emirates

I want to know the political reason why was it done so? Indians, especially the government in power, follow Hindu ideology. Why would a Muslim country do that?

Does it have anything to do with the Indian Prime Minister's charisma?

Comment: Someteimes countries with different "ideologies" can be friends :D

Comment: @hownowbrowncow, this is not about ideology. This is about politics. see my answer.

Comment: @anonymous I was referencing OPs question.

Comment: Isn't the building private? What make you think the owner couldn't just light it up at his own will?

Answer (score 11):

India and the UAE have close political and economic ties. According to [this](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/India%E2%80%93United_Arab_Emirates_relations), wiki, the UAE was responsible for 11.5% of India's exports in 2015. Due to their close ties displays of friendship like this are common between them. For example, in an [article](http://timesofindia.indiatimes.com/india/burj-khalifa-glows-with-tricolour-to-mark-indias-republic-day/articleshow/56789551.cms) detailing this event, it is also mentioned that

> Crown Prince of Abu Dhabi Mohamed bin Zayed Al Nahyan will be the
>   Chief Guest at the Republic Day parade on Thursday.

So their ties go back further than PM Modi, and this display was just part of a long running series of signals of friendship.

Also, as [another question](https://politics.stackexchange.com/questions/15364/why-does-indias-constitution-say-its-a-sovereign-socialist-secular-democratic) mentioned, India is constitutionally a secular state. It generally does not do politics based on religion. In fact pretty much all of India's major trading partners are not Hindu.

Comment: " India is constitutionally a secular state." It is a de facto Hindu supremacist country. "It generally does not do politics based on religion." --- Just go though the history and stories of BJP.

Answer (score 6):

Other than what David has mentioned, there is also another reason which is responsible for increased efforts at strengthening bilateral relations between UAE and India.

That reason is to annoy India's Arch-Nemesis, Pakistan.

Why, you ask?

Because Pakistani Parliament overwhelmingly voted [in refusal of Saudi request to join](http://www.reuters.com/article/us-yemen-security-idUSKBN0N10LO20150410) the Saudi-led [Arab alliance](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Saudi_Arabian-led_intervention_in_Yemen) fighting the Iranian backed rebels in Yemen. The Speech of Opposition leader, Aitzaz Ahsan from Pakistan People's Party on 5th day of the very heated debate on the matter can be watched [here](http://www.unewstv.com/41676/aitzaz-ahsan-complete-speech-in-joint-session-of-parliament-6th-april-2015) (In urdu language) in which he blasted the Government's ambigious stance and the proposal to send Armed forces to a war which Pakistani people did not feel was theirs. That speech turned the tide completely with the Parliament unanimously voting to decline Saudi request to send forces. To quote some points of his speech:

> "Defense Minister says that Pakistan will issue a determinate response
>   if territorial integrity of KSA is threatened. What exactly threatens
>   that, please tell us that."  
> .
> .
> .
>  "Do we have a policy
>   if Iran's territorial integrity is threatened? What about Egypt?
>   Lebanon?" 
> .
> .
> .
>  "There's 2000 miles of desert between
>   Yemen border and Saudia's big cities. How Yemen could possibly
>   threaten Saudia?" 
> .
> .
> .
>  "I can comfortably say this is
>   not a sectarian war. This is not Shia vs Sunni. This is a political
>   conflict and a civil war." 
> .
> .
> .
>  "And who exactly are
>   you going to defend? Saudi state? Saudi government? Holy cities of
>   Islam? All three are different entities. You are not clear even about
>   what exactly is your plan here but sure you will issue a determinate
>   response, won't you?" 
> .
> .
> .
>  "There is a television
>   advertisement going on nowadays. It's about a man named Bakhshu who
>   always did what he could for others. But no one ever did anything for
>   Bakhshu. Bakshu stands for everyone, no one stands for Bakhshu. Stop
>   making Bakhshus out of us."

This decision, coupled with [lack of active participation by another Sunni Non-Arab power Turkey](http://www.turkiyegazetesi.com.tr/gundem/250295.aspx) in the alliance against Shias, caused [huge outrage in Gulf countries](http://www.thenational.ae/opinion/comment/why-is-pakistan-not-supporting-its-old-friend-at-this-critical-time) who saw it as Pakistanis and Turks abandoning them in front of Iranian advances as Gulf nations have long relied on the military muscle of these two Sunni majority countries.

While Saudis themselves did not issue any hard statement or overtly hostile reaction to the Turks and the Pakistanis, UAE did so in most clear terms.

UAE’s Minister of State for Foreign Affairs Dr Anwar Mohammed Gargash [said](http://www.dawn.com/news/1175284):

> The vague and contradictory stands of Pakistan and Turkey are an
>   absolute proof that Arab security — from Libya to Yemen — is the
>   responsibility of none but Arab countries. **Tehran seems to be more**
>   **important to Islamabad and Ankara than the Gulf countries.**

He also threatened that Pakistan will pay heavy price for this stance.

This threat was followed by [a two-day visit to UAE](http://www.dawn.com/news/1201143) by Indian Prime Minister, Narendara Modi. During this visit, Indian PM and UAE's leaders reached an agreement and established an infrastructure investment fund, with the aim of reaching the [target of $75 billion](http://tribune.com.pk/story/947720/india-bid-to-halt-pakistan-projects-fails/), to support investments in the rapid expansion of next-generation infrastructure in India, especially railways, ports, roads, airports, industrial corridors and parks. This investment of 75 billion is widely seen as UAE's effort to woo new Geopolitical allies against Iran and Indian attempt to counter the 46 Billion USD planned Chinese investment in Pakistan.

In Conclusion:

1. UAE is finding new partners in region for wider political aims for containing Iran.
2. India is seeking alternatives for foreign investment as Chinese CPEC investment in Pakistan is seen as a major threat by Indian policy makers. They are also hoping to find new partners to contain Pakistan after their bid to fail the CPEC project in Gwadar by [building rival port](http://tribune.com.pk/story/1111479/iran-offers-pakistan-join-chabahar-port-deal/) in Iran [failed](http://www.dawn.com/news/1311031).
3. Religion does not play as big a role in politics as you imagine. Iraq is an Arab Muslim state, it has always supported India in Indo-Pakistan rivalry. Meanwhile, Sri-Lanka and Nepal, both Non-Muslims, are seen as good friends by Pakistanis.

So you can say UAE's antics are kind of like acts of one's ex who isn't really over you and keeps flaunting how good things are going with their new partner to make you jealous or feel bad for yourself .

Answer (score 4):

Even though, India has been the largest trading partner of UAE and 27.15% of UAE's immigrants are Indian, UAE had a strategic relationship with Pakistan in that they funded Pakistan's nuclear weapons program and helped Pakistan to smuggle various parts and accessories of Pakistan's nuclear industry. UAE's crown prince was the only foreign national who was allowed to visit Pakistan's nuclear facilities back in the 1980's. UAE funded lots of humanitarian projects in Pakistan including Hospitals, Schools, and so on.

[UAE was one of the three countries who recognized Taliban government of Afghanistan](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Islamic_Emirate_of_Afghanistan), an artificial government created by Pakistan military back in the 1997's.

**[Saudi Arabia-led intervention in Yemen](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Islamic_Military_Alliance).**

Everything suddenly started to change from April 2015 when Saudi Arabia formed a military alliance with eight Sunni majority countries to start a military operation against the Iran-backed Shia militants in Yemen. Saudi Arabia and UAE invited Pakistan to join their military alliance and to contribute to the war in Yemen. Pakistani parliament vetoed the proposal and decided to maintain neutrality apparently because of peaceful relationship with neighboring Shia Iran. [Pakistan's PM and then Chief of Army Staff Rahil Sharif even tried to mediate between Saudi Arabia and Iran to de-escalate the situation](http://www.dawn.com/news/1233773).

This non-participation started a real spat between Pakistan and the UAE. UAE openly declared that "[Pakistan would have to pay heavy price for their ambiguous stand](http://www.dawn.com/news/1175284)". In the next few months, Narendra Modi grabbed this opportunity to widen the gap between the UAE and Pakistan and signed multi-billion dollars' of trade agreements and formed a deep strategic alliance with the UAE including defense agreements.

Since then, UAE is continuously making Pakistan jealous by showing off different feats including that tri-color.

Interestingly though, Pakistan never even sent any diplomatic mission to mend the relationship with the UAE.

---

**P.S.**

Saudi Arabia's response to Pakistan's neutrality was quite different than that of the UAE.

Saudi Arabia is heavily dependent on Pakistan in the area of military training and defense analysis. Also, Pakistan is the guarantor of the security of the House of Saud. Pakistan Army always maintains a sizable presence in Saudi Arabia to provide the security of the two holy mosques in Mecca and Medina and to the Saudi government.

---

**EDIT**

On 23 March 2017, Burj Khalifa was lit up with Pakistan colors.

[image]

**Youtube Video**

- https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=MOrd2Q9FNmc

Comment: Oh wow. You and I seem to be thinking along the same lines.

Comment: @NSNoob, apparently so.LOL

Comment: So...it's a petty lover's spat where one is trying to make the other jealous?

Comment: @blip, yes. mostly. And, the situation can again start to swing in favor of Pakistan if they send troops to Yemen tomorrow. Interestingly, Pakistan never even sent any diplomatic mission to mend the relationship. I don't know why.

Comment: @anonymous hallmark needs to come out with a line of "Sorry for our international relations blunder" cards. :)

Comment: @anonymous I think that would be because Pakistani public was very much against joining the adventure and supported the parliament in its decision vehemently as it expressed the anger found in general Pakistani populace over Arab support and patronage of Wahabism in their country which is one of the key factors behind the terrorism in Pakistan.

Comment: @NSNoob, "... that would be ..." --- I couldn't follow. What was that?

Comment: Not to mention, Geopolitical situation of the region is changing rapidly. China and Russia are getting closer. Pakistan has always leaned towards China and is moving away from Western Camp while Arabs are still firmly placed there. Iran has also moved to the Russki camp. Turkey is also tilting towards China-Russia. It is interesting that before Pakistan refused, Turkish president and Pakistani PM discussed Yemen on phone so I'd not be surprised if Turkish and Pakistani response to Arab request was not coordinated mutually.

Comment: @anonymous "That would be" -> "Why Pakistan didn't send a diplomatic mission to mend the relations"

Comment: @NSNoob, "I think that would be because Pakistani public was very much against joining the adventure and supported the parliament in its decision vehemently as it expressed the anger found in general Pakistani populace over Arab support and patronage of Wahabism in their country" --- Pakistani government singlehandedly took that decision. They just used parliament as an excuse. Two reasons: (1) Pakistan is already spending $2 billion per year to fight Taliban and Balouch terrorists and (2) Pakistan army is heavily busy providing the security of $57 bln China-Pakistan economic corridor.

Comment: @NSNoob, "which is one of the key factors behind the terrorism in Pakistan." --- Wahabism isn't the key factor behind the terrorism in Pakistan. Key factor is Pakistan's cooperation with ISAF and the USA which angered various Islamist groups.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/53201/discussion-between-nsnoob-and-anonymous).

Comment: @NSNoob, "It is interesting that before Pakistan refused, Turkish president and Pakistani PM discussed Yemen on phone so I'd not be surprised if Turkish and Pakistani response to Arab request was not coordinated mutually" --- Turkey is already engaged in Syria. Also, Turkey has become Pakistan's 2nd biggest supplier of defense technology (not arms) by undertaking upgrading F-16s, integrating SLBM in Aghosta-90B, inviting Pakistan to its TFX program, and so forth.

Comment: @blip, I suspect your apparently innocent joke involves a concealed form of racism.

Comment: @anonymous that wasn't the intent.